# Google Sheets 'needs permission' to run container-bound scripts for shared users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got a Google Sheets set up with a container bound scripts tied to buttons. I wrote the scripts and am the owner of the sheets, and everything works perfectly for me.

However, the other users - who have full edit permissions on the sheets - cannot run the scripts because a pop-up says they require permission to do so. Is there a way to grant them the permissions needed to run the scripts?

Thanks!

Comment: They must authorize the scripts. Otherwise they have not granted Google the required permission to run the scripts as them. Try adding a custom menu that has an option called "Run auth", which when clicked runs the function `function triggerAuthPrompt() {}`. Have the users click the menu option, and then they will be able to Grant permission without needing to leave the Sheets UI

Comment: @cooper https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#custom_menus_in_google_docs_sheets_slides_or_forms